# How can I do WITH in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

I have this query:

```
WITH tempA AS (SELECT conversationId FROM participant WHERE userId = "aaa"),
     tempB AS (SELECT conversationId FROM participant WHERE userId = "bbb")
SELECT conversationId 
FROM tempA, tempB 
WHERE tempA.conversationId = tempB.conversationId;
```

The query will return the id of the conversation that both users participating in.

I also have an Participation Model in Sequelize:

```
const Participation = sequelize.define("participation", {
    //...attributes
});

module.exports = Participation;
```

How can I do the above query in Sequelize without using `sequelize.query`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [scopes](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/scopes.html) to get the same effect.  Here is a rough example:

```
   /* for the ON clause of JOIN */
   participation.hasMany(participation, {
      sourceKey : 'userId',
      foreignKey: 'userId',
      as: 'selfJoin'
      });

   participation.addScope('tempA', {
      attributes: ['message_id'],
      where: {userId: 'aaa'}
      });

  participation.addScope('tempB',{
      attributes: ['message_id'],
      where: {userId: 'bbb'}
      });


   participation.scope('tempB').findAll({    
      attributes: ['message_id'],
      include: [{
         model: participation.scope('tempA'),
         required: true,
         as: 'selfJoin',
         attributes: []
        }]
     });
```